# Using predicate for Orderby c# Dictionary

Tags: c#, predicate

Help me with new theme "predicate" 
I have a question to change this code for using predicate:

```
 var d = dict.OrderBy(delegate(KeyValuePair<string,int> pair) { return pair.Value; });
```

But have no idea how it's working...

Comment: It's a little unclear as to what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Predicates cannot be used with `OrderBy`. Predicates indicate whether a record should be returned at all, and return a boolean type.

Comment: May be delegate i need use?

Comment: Well, isn´t the code working as it is? From my point it should.

Comment: this code is working good, but for homework i need use other form for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And where is the problem?

`delegate(KeyValuePair<string, int> pair) { return pair.Value; }` is the same as `Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, int>`.

Thus you can easily replace your code by this:

```
var d = dict.OrderBy((KeyValuePair<string, int> pair) => pair.Value);
```

Or easier:

```
var d = dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value);
```

As the compiler can automatically infer the type of the instance within the delegate.

As an aside: a predicate is basically a method that expects an instance of your type (in your case `KeyValuePair<string, int>` and returns a `bool`, thus a `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: But `pair => pair.Value` is not a predicate... ;)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I know, because predicate is the completely whrong term here, you can´t oder by a predicate, can you?

Comment: How can i use it separatly? in a separatly delegate?

Comment: Well you could order by the result of a predicate: first all items that fail the test, then all items that pass ;)

Comment: @grek40 Sure, but this is quite trivial and supposingly not what OP needs.

Comment: @Victor The `x => x.Value`-part *is* the delegate (or if `Value` were of type `bool` that expression is named a `predicate`).

Comment: Hello) thanl you all for the ansvering!)  So i need just do it:
'code' Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, int> mypredicate = new Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, int>(ValueGetter);  var ddd = dict.OrderBy(mypredicate, new MyComparer()); class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
        {
            public int Compare(int s1, int s2)
            {
                if (s1 < s2)
                    return (-1);
                else if (s1 > s2)
                    return (1);
                else
                    return (0);
            }
        }